# In Libre Office Writer, is there a way to quickly navigate between comments?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I'm reviewing a very long document and I'd like to make meta commentary as I go, so I'm highlighting and commenting on sections with Comments. I'd like to be able to jump from comment to comment quickly so I can review them.

Is there a shortcut or command to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Display the Navigator (`View -> Navigator`)

2) In the resulting window, you should see the following:

[image]

Clicking on a comment will bring you directly to it.

The first row of icons allows for navigation (explore the options)

Clicking on the second icon of the second row ("Content View") will show only comments:

[image]